# count elements in pandas dataframe with gropuby and attach them to existing dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pandas-groupby

I have a pandas dataframe with the following structure:

```
date    ticker Name 
2/1/10  aaa    zzz  
2/1/10  aaa    yyy  
2/5/10  bbb    xxx  
2/5/10  ccc    www  
2/5/10  ccc    qqq  
2/5/10  ddd    vvv  
2/6/10  aaa    zzz
```

I would like to add a column with the number of times the same ticker appears on the same date to every row. so the output would look like this:

```
date    ticker Name count 
2/1/10  aaa    zzz  2
2/1/10  aaa    yyy  2
2/5/10  bbb    xxx  1
2/5/10  ccc    www  2
2/5/10  ccc    qqq  2
2/5/10  ddd    vvv  1
2/6/10  aaa    zzz  1
```

At the moment I was able to get the number of times each ticker appears at the same date but in a reduced dataframe so I can't fit it elegantly back to the original data frame.
this is what I was trying:

```
grpby2 = df2.groupby(['Date','Ticker'])
tmp = grpby2.agg({'Ticker':'max','Name':'count'}).reset_index(1,drop=True).reset_index(drop=False)
```

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using `groupby` + `transform` with `'count'`:

```
df['count'] = df.groupby(['date', 'ticker']).transform('count')

print(df)

     date ticker Name  count
0  2/1/10    aaa  zzz      2
1  2/1/10    aaa  yyy      2
2  2/5/10    bbb  xxx      1
3  2/5/10    ccc  www      2
4  2/5/10    ccc  qqq      2
5  2/5/10    ddd  vvv      1
6  2/6/10    aaa  zzz      1
```

Also works with `len`, but this option is significantly slower as it does not utilise optimized functions indicated by a string.

Comment: Using the `string` codes tells `transform` to use the built in functions that have usually been optimized.  Use `transform('max')` instead of `transform(max)`... so on and so forth.  I believe the source even checks if what is passed is a `ufunc` and treats it differently.

Comment: @piRSquared, Thank you, I had a feeling it had to do with using Python built-ins on NumPy arrays instead of NumPy vectorised functions.

Comment: @piRSquared and @jpp A question, what is the best practice to add the column to the df. If I try the code as is I get this: ValueError: Wrong number of items passed 8, placement implies 1. so I did this: `df['count'] = ''` and then: `df['count'] = df.groupby(['date', 'ticker']).transform('count')`

Comment: @AsherMetzger, Not sure, I can't reproduce your error. The code works with the data you provided.

Answer (score 3):

### `np.bincount` and `pd.factorize`

```
f, u = pd.factorize(list(zip(df.date, df.ticker)))
df.assign(Count=np.bincount(f)[f])

     date ticker Name  Count
0  2/1/10    aaa  zzz      2
1  2/1/10    aaa  yyy      2
2  2/5/10    bbb  xxx      1
3  2/5/10    ccc  www      2
4  2/5/10    ccc  qqq      2
5  2/5/10    ddd  vvv      1
6  2/6/10    aaa  zzz      1
```